# Query SQL Server 2000 for table creation and alteration queries

Tags: sql-server-2000, backup, database-backups

I'm looking for a way to get all table creation and alteration queries attached to a database, in SQL Server 2000. Is this stored in a system table, or is there a built in method to remake them?

Goal: to extract the schema for customizable backups.

My research so far turned up nothing. My Google-Fu is weak...

Comment: Can you define "queries attached to a database"? And can you explain what your "customizable backups" will achieve that `BACKUP DATABASE` won't?

Comment: @AaronBertrand By queries attached to a database I mean all creation and alteration queries that are relevant to the tables owned by a database. I need to create backups of certain sets of tables, not all tables as `BACKUP DATABASE` would do.

Comment: You could put those tables on their own filegroup, and do a filegroup-based backup.

Comment: @AaronBertrand That'd be great! I'll look for some documentation on filegroups. If I can automate their creation, that would work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that I don't know that there's a way to specify which filegroup a stored procedure is on (other than the default). So what you may consider, in order to at least keep the script repository backup small, is:

1. create a filegroup called non_data_objects, and make it the default (instead of PRIMARY).
2. create a filegroup for each set of tables, and create those tables there.
3. backup each set of tables by filegroup, and always include a backup of non_data_objects so that you have the current set of procedures, functions etc. that belong to those tables (even though you'll also get the others). Because 1. will only contain the metadata for non-data, it should be relatively small.

You might also consider just using a different database for each set of tables. Other than using three-part naming in your scripts that need to reference the different sets, there really is no performance difference. And this makes your backup/recovery plan much simpler.

Comment: Yeah, the different database part was the initial approach. It's a legacy program, though (the SQL Server version is a sign of its age), that's too poorly designed and badly integrated with other systems to be easily changed.

Comment: If it were 2005 you could easily use synonyms to mask all of that. On 2000, well you're dealing with 12 year old out-of-support technology, so you'll have some limitations. :-)

Comment: Well, part of the backup operation is for migration to a newer platform, so there's hope yet.